# How do I remove the tab Default Programs command object from my Start menu?

Tags: windows-8, windows-registry, start-menu

I was in my registry (using regedit) to create a backup, I then restarted my computer and noticed a tab saying Default Programs command object.

I'm running Windows 8 with [StartIsBack](http://www.startisback.com). I uninstalled StartIsBack to avoid seeing the tab but after resolving this issue I would like to use it.

Comment: If you reinstall StartIsBack, does it still show? Have you tried a [system restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc) back to before you were in the registry?  What _have_ you tried to rectify this (aside from uninstalling StartIsBack)?

Comment: ask the developer: http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/158666-start-is-back-21-release/

Answer (score 0):

If StartIsBack is indeed just like the traditional start button, just right click the Start button, choose Properties, click the Customize button on the Start Menu tab, then uncheck "Default Programs"

Comment: The option to remove the tab default programs command object isn't there. However i could remove anything else which is wierd

Comment: Boo.  I'll dig some more.  It may not be in the list because StartIsBack guys couldn't find how to remove it either :)

Comment: If you delete the shortcut to Default Programs from C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools does that get rid of that command object?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when registry is corrupted or sud.dll is deleted. Some evil tool breaks this, you may try System Restore rollback.